# T-Test on Libre Office

Tags: excel, pvalue

The p-value for the paired t-test function on LibreOffice is different for whether data is sorted and unsorted, to the point where the p-value is not reliable. The t critical value has stayed the same though. How do I get a reliable p-value on LibreOffice?